# Comment traduire « second guessing » ?

Tags: traduction, expressions-idiomatiques, jeux

L'expression a plus d'un sens, mais je cherche celle qui signifie deviner, extrapoler ou spéculer sur des faits qui ne sont pas connus. Je parle ici d'une mécanique de jeu souvent confondue avec le bluff : il s'agit de baser sa stratégie sur l'anticipation de la stratégie de l'adversaire. En d'autres termes, on joue au « je sais que tu sais que je sais… » en essayant de savoir si l'adversaire a lui-même adapté sa stratégie à la nôtre.

Un bon exemple de jeu serait le « [6 qui prend](http://www.trictrac.net/index.php3?id=jeux&rub=detail&inf=detail&jeu=177url/) », la stratégie ne peut pas être gagnante à tous les coups, ça dépend de comment jouent les adversaires.

Quel est le terme francophone pour décrire cette mécanique ?

Comment: J'ai ajouté un petit truc à la question puisque cette définition de *second guessing* n'est pas la seule.

Comment: Ce ne serait pas la "théorie des jeux"?

Comment: Ok Kareen! @oli, la théorie des jeux, c'est un terme bien vague qui regroupe bien des choses. C'est comme si je demandais comment on appelle le phénomène de transformation d'un liquide en solide et que tu me répondais « la physique ».

Comment: Est-ce qu'interpréter ou prédire serait les thermes que tu recherches ?

Comment: Non, ce que je recherche n'est pas un terme comme ça. Lorsque tu parles d'un jeu, tu dis que c'est un jeu de placement, un jeu de bluff ou un jeu de chance. Comment dit-on que c'est un jeu de « second guessing » en français ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cela ressemble beaucoup à **une stratégie de contrecoups**

Comment: Ça parait être une piste intéressante, mais est-ce que tu pourrais développer sur d'où ça vient, et fournir une attestation d'emploi, siouplait ? :)

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/contre-coup/15737 donne des définitions de à contrecoup. En faire une stratégie revient à utiliser la technique des arts martiaux qui utilise la force de son adversaire pour lui faire subir des effets inattendus, voire "douloureux".

Answer (score 2):

Dans le langage commun, je ne sais pas. Mais, en algorithmique de la théorie des jeux, on appelle ce genre de stratégie **algorithme minimax**.

Plus d'information sur [Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithme_minimax).

Ce n'est pas exactement pareil. C'est plus "Si je fais ça, tu feras ça, alors je ferai ça..."

Comment: Je crois que je suis surtout d'accord avec "ce n'est pas exactement pareil", malheureusement.

Answer (score 1):

J'appelle ça des **jeux de logiciens**… comme ceux qui font les annonces à la belote, qui étalent les cartes, et qui disent « ah, vous avez gagné alors » parce qu'ils peuvent raisonner en supposant que chacun fera le coup *optimal*.

Mais je crois pas qu'il n'y ait de terme connu pour décrire ce comportement. Liés, mais pas exactement identiques : **« avoir un (ou plusieurs) coup(s) d'avance »**, ou tout simplement **« anticiper »**.